# Is there a way to have an array of multiple types in proto3?

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto, proto3

I want to design a proto3 message from this Cesium class:[Cesium Class](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/czml-writer/wiki/CartographicRadiansValue). It is an array containing [string, double, double, double]. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can create arbitrarily long messages like those shown in your link because your client and server must agree on the number and order of fields before transfer.

`[Time, Longitude, Latitude, Height, Time, Longitude, Latitude, Height, ...]`

*Problem: without pre-defining many field numbers, how do I pass this many fields?*

**Option 1**

Instead, you can create your own message type to represent a single instance:

```
message CartographicRadians {
    string time = 1;
    double longitude = 2;
    double latitude = 3;
    double height = 4;
}
```

Then [use the custom type](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#other) as a field. Here the [`repeated`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#specifying_field_rules) keyword indicates that you can send more than one `CartographicRadians` in the `CartographicRadiansArray`.

```
message CartographicRadiansArray {
    repeated CartographicRadians entries = 1;
}
```

**Option 2**

Another approach would be to create a self-recursive message which would function closer to the stream-like format described above.

```
message CartographicRadians {
    string time = 1;
    double longitude = 2;
    double latitude = 3;
    double height = 4;
    CartographicRadians nextEntry = 5;
}
```

Comment: That would yield an array of CartographicRadians, What I need is one array following this: [Time, Longitude, Latitude, Height, Time, Longitude, Latitude, Height, ...].

Comment: See the edit I just made. I don't think what you are looking for is possible. You will either need to parse the array of messages back into a single object at the client or you will need a technology like JSON that allows arbitrarily long messages.

Comment: I think your right on this, in the cesium documentation there is an option to use seconds past the epoch, hopefully would be considered a double and I can just use that.

Comment: Leave the question open, someone who knows better than me might come along. `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

The best option to `serialize/deserialize` an array with different types in `protobuf` is this one:

```
message Types{
  oneof types {
    string str= 1;
    double dou = 2;
  }
}

message CartographicRadians {
  repeated Types list = 1;
```